# Gradle, merge class from root and sub project

Tags: jar, gradle

I want to merge the .class files from a subproject in the main jar file.

I try

```
into('') {
    from project(":audit-reactive-lib").buildDir;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you want is a [big jar](https://github.com/akhikhl/gradle-onejar).
If you want to code it on your own, your do it like [this](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/one_jar_package_a_groovy_application_together_with_its_dependency_jars_into_a_single_executable_jar_file):

```
jar { 
    from {
        project(":audit-reactive-lib").sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
    }
}
```

Next time search before you ask, or take more effort in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this code agregate all the files in the same jar. I would like to merge only the main and subproject jar. Not the dependencies.

Comment: I hope now it matches your needs. It should add the class files of subproject to your main jar.